# Refresh a screen after a modal confirmation(Angular)

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, settimeout

I am stuck.

```
confirmDeleteSubmission(content) {
   this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' }).result.then((result) => {
      if (result == 'ok') {
         this.deleteSubmissionEvent.emit('delete');
         // refresh the screen
         setTimeout(() => {

         }, 1000);
      }
   });
}
```

I am trying to get `setTimeout` to work. Basically after a user clicks on ok, the whole screen refreshes.
how do i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain little more about your problem? May with some example in stackblitz or some images? And are you using reactive forms or just Forms ? :-)

Comment: Have you tried with `window.location.reload()` ?

Comment: In SPA's like Angular you want to avoid page refreshes. This will make a full reload of the app. You can update the current page or route to an other page for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of refreshing the page call respective API's to refresh the data of the page-

```
confirmDeleteSubmission(content){
this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
  if(result == 'ok'){
    this.deleteSubmissionEvent.emit('delete');
    // refresh the screen
    setTimeout(() => {
      // call your get data API's
      getNewListOfItemsAfterDeletion();
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: If it solves your issue then you can accept my post as an answer.

Comment: yeah, thanx. I kept looping through wrong function within the setTimeout, that is where I began to doubt my JS skills. :) thank you again